# Cannot detect if user pressed Cancel button on WKWebView sign-in-with-apple pop-up

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, sign-in-with-apple

I have a WKWebView which loads url of type "https://appleid.apple.com/auth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=...&redirect_uri=...&response_mode=..." and so on. When it's loaded I see apple auth pop-up like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iG7AT.png)

I want to close viewController with this webView if user taps Cancel on this pop-up but I can't detect this event. Adding event listener like this is not working:

```
let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
let source = "document.addEventListener('AppleIDSignInOnFailure', (error) => { window.webkit.messageHandlers.iosListener.postMessage('Got error'); })"
let script = WKUserScript(source: source, injectionTime: .atDocumentStart, forMainFrameOnly: false)
        
config.userContentController.addUserScript(script)
config.userContentController.add(self, name: "iosListener")
webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: config)
```

Could anybody please tell me if there is any way to detect if pop-up was closed?

Comment: did you ever figure this one out?

Comment: @sambecker I found a workaround, not sure that was a good solution but it works for me. App fires UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification when Cancel button is tapped so when I get this notification I check (with a 0.5s delay) it's not because user is successfully authorized or continued authorization in webView (in this cases webView didStartProvisionalNavigation func is called so I set flag there). If flag is false I close viewController

Comment: Thank you @AnnaV! I ended up doing something similar using `sceneWillResignActive` and `sceneDidBecomeActive`. What a crazy issue.